# php function to check if spam field has value1 or value2 or value 3, then proceed to send mail or show erro

Tags: php, html, compare

I'm trying to set up a spam check for my contact form.

The spam check will be a simple text field where the user can enter the answer in 3 possible values.

How would I go about checking the contents of the string (spam field) in php and combine this with the "If".

It would be like

If spamfield=XXXXXX or YYYYY or ZZZZZ then
send e-mail
Else
show error message

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if(in_array($spamField, array('xxxxxx', 'yyyyyy', 'zzzzzz')))

Comment: much cleaner than the _OR way_

Answer (score 1):

```
if($spamfield == "XXXXXX" || $spamfield == "YYYYY" || $spamfield == "ZZZZZ")
{
   send_mail();
}
```

|| is the operator OR

Answer (score 0):

```
$spamfield = $_POST["spamfield"];
if ($spamfield == "XXXXXX" || $spamfield == "YYYYYYYY" || $spamfield == "ZZZZZZZ")
    mail(...);
else
    echo "Error!";
```